# Postgres syntax error with creat when use $$

Tags: sql, postgresql, migration, database-migration

I want execute next script migration.
But i catch syntax error.
How can i resolve it?

Script example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION __execute(TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN EXECUTE $1; END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION __index_exists(TEXT, TEXT, TEXT) RETURNS bool as $$
SELECT exists(SELECT 1 FROM pg_indexes WHERE (schemaname, tablename, indexname) = ($1, $2, $3));
$$ language sql STRICT;

DO $$ BEGIN IF __my_function('true') THEN
SELECT __execute($$
    CREATE INDEX "test_idx"
    ON test_table
    USING btree (column_name);
    $$)
WHERE NOT __index_exists('public', 'test_table', 'test_idx');
END IF; END; $$;
```

Error:

```
SQL State  : 42601
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think postgresql get confused between dollar quoting inside function, probably if you give it a tag name will solve the issue

```
DO $$ BEGIN IF __my_function('true') THEN
perform __execute($param$ CREATE INDEX "test_idx"
    ON test_table
    USING btree (column_name);$param$)
WHERE NOT __index_exists('public', 'test_table', 'test_idx');
END IF; END; $$;
```

Comment: But the argument is passed as (dollar-quoted) `text`...

Comment: ERROR: query has no destination for result data
If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.


So i use PERFORM and its work. But also i dont checked is index exist)

Comment: @NewSheriff you have to replace 'select` with 'perform` since your function doesn't return anything/. see updated asnwer